# FormView or not?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, wizard, formview

I have an ASP.NET page with a Wizard control containing several pages of form fields. The data is collected and inserted to a database from the code behind page. I need to set this form up so you can not only insert, but edit a record as well. Since the form is long and complex, I would rather use the existing one and not make a duplicate one for editing, especially since I want to keep both forms exactly the same and any edits would have to be made to both. But it looks like this is what I need to do if I'm going to databind it. But this would also involve putting the Wizard inside of a FormView, and then I'd have to use FindControl to access any of the fields which would mean altering all my already-existing code (which of course would be time-consuming). So should I manually enter all the values from the code behind instead of databinding it? Which is better, to use a FormView and have duplicate forms (plus have to go in and redo the way I access the fields), or to do everything from the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to Go Ahead using `FormView`, as using DataBind control you have more control the functionality and layout `Insert/Edit/View` template. Since you have specified that your form is very complex and long, if you control from code behind you have to do lot of work to handle this in code behind and lot code required.

Since I have personal experience to develope very complex form using `FormView` and it was easy for me bind the Value in directly in formview instead if you `assign/Get` Values of each conrol in code behind and sometimes you have to hide.

Answer (score 1):

I cheat in this circumstance. :)

Create each screen as 2 separate user controls
One for edit, and one for view
Then you get access to all you usual coding
Then embed the controls into the Wizard/FormView